# Hovering on element activates hover CSS for another element

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm making a menu with an icon and some text, like this:

[image]

The problem is, I want the icon to be "highlighted" when I hover over the tab, instead of having to hover above the tiny icon. So this is what happens now:

[image]

[image]

So my question is how can I hover on one element (the tab is a div), and that activates the hover CSS for another element (the icon).

This is the code for the icon:
(HTML)

```
<a href="#" class="menubutton">
   <span id="playicon"></span> Servers
</a>
```

(CSS)

```
#playicon {
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background-image:url("img/svg/play2.svg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
}

#playicon:hover {
    background-image:url(img/svg/play_hover.svg);
}
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the HTML you give, you need to change the second rule to

```
.menubutton:hover #playicon {
    background-image:url(img/svg/play_hover.svg);
}
```

This rule applies to `#playicon` when it is a descendant of a hovered `.menubutton`, which is what you want (using the child selector `.menubutton:hover > #playicon` might be a good idea, although it won't make any practical difference).

Also, please note that having a `<span>` like this identified by an `id` is somewhat strange -- it looks like you would have multiples of this span on the same page, and ids need to be unique. If you do have multiples, replace the `id` with a class.

Comment: Ok thanks, I changed it to an `id` incase javascript was needed for the hover, because javascript can't change classes (without libraries I think).

Comment: @August: It can change classes just fine through the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) property, it's just that the possibility of having multiple classes at once makes the manipulation less straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
#element1:hover #element2
```

[Live example, with more advanced css techniques](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/#.UhEQCX-KKwQ)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:hover` pseudo class on the menubutton instead of the icon

```
#playicon {
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background-image:url("img/svg/play2.svg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menubutton:hover #playicon {
    background-image:url(img/svg/play_hover.svg);
}
```